# Sending emails from a google sheet based on the two or more criteria

Tags: google-apps-script

I hope that you can help, I have a spreadsheet in Google which tracks new requests, when a requester changes a cell to yes, the first scrip will send an email to notify an approve-er of a new request, a copy is also sent to an administrator.

On a approval, the approve-er may set another cell to yes this triggers a second email to be sent to senior admin to confirm the changes has been approved and to confirm that the action can now be carried out.

I have got both scrips to work independently , but I am unable to get them to work within the same project, can you please advise on the best way to achieve this?

This is my Approve-er Code

```
var admin_email='admin@myemail.com'; //<- update your email address here

function triggerOnEdit(e)
{
  sendEmailOnApproval(e);
}

function showMessageOnApproval(e)
{
  var edited_row = checkStatusIsApproved(e);
  if(edited_row > 0)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Row # "+edited_row+" Yes!");
  }
}

function showMessageOnUpdate(e)
{
  var range = e.range;
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("range updated " +   range.getA1Notation());  
}

function checkStatusIsApproved(e)
{
  var range = e.range;
  
  if(range.getColumn() <= 9 && 
     range.getLastColumn() >=9 )
  {
    var edited_row = range.getRow();
    
    var status = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(edited_row,9).getValue();
    if(status == 'Yes')
    {
      return edited_row;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

function sendEmailOnApproval(e)
{
  var approved_row = checkStatusIsApproved(e);
  
  if(approved_row <= 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  
  sendEmailByRow(approved_row);
}

function sendEmailByRow(row)
{
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,row,4).getValues();
  var row_values = values[0];
  
  var mail = composeApprovedEmail(row_values);
  
  //Uncomment this line for testing
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" subject is "+mail.subject+"\n message "+mail.message);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(admin_email,mail.subject,mail.message);

  var candidate_email = composeCandidateEmail(row_values);
  
   MailApp.sendEmail(candidate_email.email,candidate_email.subject,candidate_email.message);
}

function composeApprovedEmail(row_values)
{
  var first_name = row_values[0];
  
  var last_name = row_values[1];
  
  var email = row_values[2];

  var message = "A new Post 16 Request has been log by: "+first_name+ "\nhttps://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15a1f2GJMOSHQop3vdmGS8eH9-Uq_9KFD1sY7S_8Dhaw/edit?usp=sharing";

  var subject = "New Post 16 Change Request ";
  
  return({message:message,subject:subject});
}

function composeCandidateEmail(row_values)
{
  var first_name = row_values[1];
  
  var last_name = row_values[0];
  
  var email = row_values[2];

  var subject =  "New Post 16 Change Request";
  
  var message = "Dear "+first_name+"\n\n"+
    "A new request has been logged on the Post 16 Change Log by "+last_name+".\n\nPlease can you approve this request and update the Post 16 Database if required.\n\n\nRegards\n\nThe Data Team\n";
    //... etc
     
  
  return({message:message,subject:subject, email:email });
}
```

This is second code.

```
    var admin_email='Admin@my.com'; //<- update your email address here
 
function triggerOnEdit(e)
{
  sendEmailOnApproval(e);
}
 
function showMessageOnApproval(e)
{
  var edited_row = checkStatusIsApproved(e);
  if(edited_row > 0)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Row # "+edited_row+" Yes!");
  }
}
 
function showMessageOnUpdate(e)
{
  var range = e.range;
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("range updated " +   range.getA1Notation());  
}
 
function checkStatusIsApproved(e)
{
  var range = e.range;
  
  if(range.getColumn() <= 11 && 
     range.getLastColumn() >=11 )
  {
    var edited_row = range.getRow();
    
    var status = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(edited_row,11).getValue();
    if(status == 'Yes')
    {
      return edited_row;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
 
function sendEmailOnApproval(e)
{
  var approved_row = checkStatusIsApproved(e);
  
  if(approved_row <= 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  
  sendEmailByRow(approved_row);
}
 
function sendEmailByRow(row)
{
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,row,4).getValues();
  var row_values = values[0];
  
  var mail = composeApprovedEmail(row_values);
  
  //Uncomment this line for testing
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" subject is "+mail.subject+"\n message "+mail.message);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(admin_email,mail.subject,mail.message);
 
 }
 
function composeApprovedEmail(row_values)
{
  var first_name = row_values[0];
  
  var last_name = row_values[1];
  
  var email = row_values[2];
 
  var message = "A new Post 16 Request has been log by: "+first_name+ " and the Post 16 Database has been updated. \n\nCan you please confirm that his is the case and update the change log.";
 
  var subject = "New Post 16 Change Request | Database updated ";
  
  return({message:message,subject:subject});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I am unable to get them to work within the same project'? What happens?

Comment: If you have simply copied both scripts in then this will not work, as you can only have one function with a given name in a project, and in this case both scripts have functions with exactly the same name (when you tell it to run `showMessageOnUpdate`, how does it know *which* one?)

Comment: I suppose you are using onEdit, this trigger can't be used with the sendEmail function. You should add a trigger by action , for example : SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('example menu').addItem('example item, 'function_to_trigger');

Comment: Basically @RafaGuillermo What I want to happen is for when the request is added to the change log that it sends an email to the approve-er, they then access the change log and approve it which send an email on to the administrator, both require a 'Yes' to be input in one of two cells, so been using the onedit trigger to trigger the email to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can check which cell has been edited and run a function based on the cell.*

#### Code Example:

You'll want to use an `onEdit(e)` simple trigger function bound to the sheet, and only run the respective code if the correct cell was edited:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const cellForEditRequest = "C8" // for example
  const cellForApproverEdit = "D8" // for example

  const editedCell = e.range.getA1Notation()

  if (editedCell == cellForEditRequest) {
    // edit request code
  }
  else if (editedCell == cellForApproverEdit) {
    // administrator email code
  }
}
```

Remember:

- You need to make sure all functions are in the same file
- You need to make sure all functions have different names
- You will need to set the cells to check for in the first two lines of the `onEdit()` function.
- You will need to make this an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) as methods that require authorisation (such as to send an email) ***can not*** be run from a simple trigger.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)